# Pass args to Named Routes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to pass information to named routes in dart. I am using Bloc as the state management technique. Here is the code snippet.

```
class ChatRoomScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChatRoomScreen({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as ChatRoom;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(args.chatName),
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}

class ChatRoom {
  String chatName;
  ChatRoom({required this.chatName});
}
```

Do I need to make alterations in AppRoutesScreen? If so please let me know. This is the code

```
class AppRoutes {
  Route onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings args) {
    switch (args.name) {
      
      case AppRoutesNames.chatRoom:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const ChatRoomScreen());

      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const IncorrectRoute());
    }
  }
}
```

This is where I am pushing the screen

```
BlocBuilder<SearchCubit, SearchState>(
                    builder: ((context, state) {
                  if (state is FoundUser) {
                    return ListTile(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppRoutesNames.chatRoom,
                            arguments:
                                ChatRoom(chatName: state.user[Constants.name]));
                      },
                      subtitle: Text(state.user[Constants.email]),
                      title: Text(state.user[Constants.name]),
                    );
                  }
                  return Container();
                }))
```

But all I am getting is an error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building ChatRoomScreen(dirty, dependencies:
[_ModalScopeStatus]):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'ChatRoom' in type cast

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  ChatRoomScreen
  ChatRoomScreen:file:///Users/arjunmalhotra/Desktop/arjun_malhotra/flutter_Dev/my_projects/chat/lib/utils/routes/app_ro
  utes.dart:25:56

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      ChatRoomScreen.build (package:chat/views/chat/chat_screen.dart:7:61)
#1      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5551:49)
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5481:15)
#3      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5197:7)
#4      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5463:5)
#5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5457:5)
```

Do I have some errors while passing information? I'd gladly provide more information if necessary.

Comment: You are basically passing null type in Flutter. Check ChatRoom(chatName: state.user?[Constants.name])

Comment: Yes i just checked it does

Comment: i think the problem is in onGenerateRoute, case chat room, you are returning an empty screen with no passed data to chat screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have shared a example have a look

// Routing

```
case templateViewRoute:
  {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => TemplateViewScreen(
        templateViewScreenArgs: ModalRoute.of(context)!
            .settings
            .arguments as TemplateViewScreenArgs,
      ),
      settings: settings,
    );
  }
```

// TemplateViewScreen

```
class TemplateViewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final TemplateViewScreenArgs templateViewScreenArgs;

  const TemplateViewScreen({Key? key, required this.templateViewScreenArgs})
      : super(key: key);
}
```

// TemplateViewArgs

```
class TemplateScreenArgs {
  final String medicineSearchOfferDataResult;

  const TemplateScreenArgs({required this.medicineSearchOfferDataResult});
}
```

// Navigation

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
  templateViewRoute,
  arguments: TemplateViewScreenArgs(
    medicineSearchOfferDataResult: "data",
  ),
);
```

Comment: Tried this but didn't work

Comment: Share Your Code Snippet